# ListView onItemClick not called

Tags: android, listview, android-fragments, android-listview, android-4.0-ice-cream-sandwich

I've seen all the related questions, and tried their answers. I have a ListView inside a fragment and it's `onItemClick` method is called when inside one activity, but not called when in another one. Everything else is the same. I've tried:

- Changing `android:clickable` explicitly.
- Changing `android:focusable` and `android:focusableInTouchMode` explicitly.
- Calling `listView.setItemsCanFocus`.
- Adding `android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants"` attribute both on fragment and activity root.

Still, it's not working. It's the same fragment with same adapter, which doesn't have conditionals about being in which activity. However, in one activity it works perfectly, and in another, `onItemClick` is not called. I'm on ICS. Why would this happen?

**UPDATE:**

Here is the relevant code in my fragment:

```
dataSource = (ArrayList<Map<String, Object>>) task.getResult();     
FeedAdapter adapter = new FeedAdapter(getActivity(), dataSource, getUser());     
ListView list = (ListView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.listView);     
list.setItemsCanFocus(true);    //just trying these 
list.setOnItemClickListener(self);     
list.setAdapter(adapter);     
adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();     
if (dataSource.size() == 0) {     
    noPostsLabel.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);     
}
```

And in my adapter:

```
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    View view;
    final Map<String, Object> post = objects.get(position);
    LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(getContext());
    if (convertView == null || convertView.getId() == R.id.headerRoot) {
        view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item_post_layout, parent, false);
    } else {
        view = convertView;
    }
    view.setClickable(false); //just trying these two now, they weren't here originally
    view.setFocusable(false);
    //populate
    view.setTag(post);

    [...] //populate the cell. very long code, redacted.

    return view;

}
```

**UPDATE 2:**

I've also realized some cells are also not selectable in my "working" activity too, when they have a visible HorizontalScrollView within the cell (I have file attaching feature and it's only visible when there are files. Otherwise, it's in `GONE` visibility state). I have no idea why it's causing such trouble.

**UPDATE 3:**

I've also found out that views inside the cell are responsive. It's just the cell view itself which is not taking input.

**UPDATE 4:**

I've ended up moving the tap handler logic to the cell layout itself, instead of relying on list view's handler. I know it's not a good practice but I had to meet a deadline. Besides, it's working pretty smooth now. I'm not closing/answering the question as the technical problem is still present and I haven't found a real solution to it. I've just used a workaround to meet my project deadline.

Comment: Some code might help with solving the issue.

Comment: @EugeneH from where?

Comment: From your two fragments and activity that are relevant to the post. The interface callbacks (if any), list implementation.

Comment: It seems you did your research. My wild guess is the common error of not using the correct view for the findViewById(). Besides that, please post relevant code for the ListView and setting the listener, like setOnItemClickListener.

Comment: When in situations like this, I usually find that trying to reduce the problem to the bare minimum helps a lot in both thinking about it and figuring out potential solutions.  Chances are, doing that will magically make clear what's going on :) - but even if not, you'll then have a nice compact test to post so more people can help out.

Comment: @TheOriginalAndroid I've put the relevant code.

Comment: @EugeneH I've put the relevant code.

Comment: can you please show class implementation e.g inheritance and implementation for activity and fragment?

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure of your problem and I don't see the full code to debug.
I'll submit a sample code which normally should work in a Fragment.

```
@Override
public void onViewCreated(View view, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
   ListView list = (ListView) view.findViewById(R.id.listView);

   list.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
      @Override
      public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int positi   on, long id) {
          Log.d(TAG, "onItemClick");
     }
   });
```

Notes:

- I don't use root or any other cached object. I use the view parameter for calling findViewById().
- I don't know self also. Instead I instantiated a new view or AdapterView.

Comment: `self` was a final reference to `this` within the method, to be called from inner class.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried setting callbacks for the fragments? That's the way Android recommends it. You can check out - https://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/communicating.html#Deliver

Comment: How do I do that, what does it have to do with my case?

Comment: The webpage is for communication between fragments and Activity, also called interface/callback. This is not like an event listener, e.g. onItemClick().